# Does CREATE waste space?

Tags: memory, forth, gforth

In gforth, CREATE, by itself, creates a variable, which takes some memory space: a few bytes to store the value plus two instructions to put the address on the stack and return:

```
create a  ok
42 a !  ok
a @ . 42  ok
```

If instead of a variable you want to create an 80-byte buffer, you can write

```
: TAMPON CREATE 80 ALLOT DOES> + ;
```

but those 80 bytes would come after the bytes taken by CREATE for the default variable, which is a waste.

Does CREATE waste space or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE` does not waste space. It "does not allocate data space in *name*'s data field" (see [6.1.1000 `CREATE`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/CREATE)).

This example shows incorrect usage:

> ```
> create a
> 42 a !
> a @ .
> ```

At this moment, `a` and `here` returns the same address:

```
a here = . \ it prints "-1"
```

So you have to reserve required space before use:

```
1 cells allot
a cell+ here = . \ it prints "-1"
```

Comment: Now I understand, but it took me while.

Comment: Now I also undertand the difference between CREATE and VARIABLE.